# Why is this $O(\log \log n)$?

Tags: logarithms, asymptotics

Why is this $O(\log \log n)$?

```
 // Here c is a constant greater than 1   
   for (int i = 2; i <=n; i = pow(i, c)) { 
       // some O(1) expressions
   }
```

I am trying to understand how I would derive the time complexity of something like this.

Comment: Please write your questions in a way that knwoledge of the syntax of some unspecified language is not needed. What does pow(i,c) mean $i^c$ or $c^i$ or something else.

Comment: Because if $N=2^{c^n}$ then $n=\log_c\log_2N$ hence $n=O(\log\log N)$.

Comment: @Did I think my problem was seeing what $N$ needed to be stated as $(N = 2^{c^n})$, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that on the $k$th iteration we have
$$i=2^{c^k}$$
The loop ends if $i>n$, meaning
$$2^{c^k}>n$$
$$c^k>\log_2 n$$
$$k\log_2 c>\log_2\log_2 n$$
$$k>\log_2\log_2 n/\log_2 c$$
Thus there are fewer than a constant multiple of $\log_2\log_2 n$ iterations.

Comment: I think third line should be $k \log c > \log \log_2 n$ which leads to $k > \log_c \log_2 n$, perhaps?

Comment: What I mean is on the third line you apply $\log$ to the left side but $\log_2$ to the right

Comment: Oh that was a typo. I'll fix it.